# Can I rotate objects the with 3 orbits around it like in Unity or SketchUp?

Tags: transforms, 3d-manipulator

I have a really hard time percieving depth on screen so after I move or rotate an objects it ends up anywhere but in the place I wanted. The problem with moving the object is easily solved by holing the axis and moving the object along it, but I can't find anything like this for rotating. Is there a setting or an addon I can use to have 3 orbits around the object so I can rotate them instead of directly rotating the object? I tried rotating objects while holding x/y/z, but that didn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press <kbd>R</kbd> the object will rotate on the view axis. If you press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>, the object will rotate on the X axis only. If you press <kbd>R</kbd> twice it will rotate on both axis except the view one. If you press <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> it will rotate in both axis except X.

If you set the curve in the selector on the header of the 3D view you will have your "Rotators" around the object.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [manipulator widget](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/manipulators.html) can be changed to rotate or scale. Look for three little buttons at in the 3D view header, a little left of center.
[image: the manipulator widget buttons in the 3D view header]
The button with the round curve will give you the rotation widget.